# Configure error installing Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OS 10.10 with rvm and Homebrew

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew, osx-yosemite

*Note for those thinking of marking this duplicate: yes, my XCode tools are installed and up to date.*

---

I started this morning with a system having neither rvm or Homebrew, and was able to install rvm and Ruby 1.9.3 successfully after overriding the default Homebrew installation directory, changing it from `/usr/local` to `/opt/brew`.

This afternoon, though, after seeing various warnings about possible weird behavior for some Homebrew recipes if installed anywhere other than `/usr/local`, I decided to blow all that away and reinstall with Homebrew in the default location.

Now, what worked this morning doesn't work: I get the error below (from `configure.log`):

`` [2015-02-04 15:39:24] ./configure
current path: /Users/dmoles/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551
PATH=/usr/local/opt/gcc48/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/dmoles/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/apache-ant-1.9/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3/bin:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin:/Users/dmoles/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin
command(7): ./configure --prefix=/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/dmoles/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'. ``

My guess is that this morning it was using the XCode toolchain, and this afternoon it's using Homebrew's, which for some reason isn't working. But it's not clear to me just how that would happen, since I can see above that `rvm` is playing various games with `$PATH`. (My usual `$PATH`: `/Users/dmoles/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/apache-ant-1.9/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3/bin:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin:/Users/dmoles/.rvm/bin` -- without all the `/usr/local/opt` at the beginning or the extra `/usr/local/bin` at the end.)

My `rvm` version is 1.26.10; `gcc-48` is Homebrew gcc48 4.8.4.